# Regex Letters, Numbers, Dashes, and Underscores

Tags: regex

Im not sure how I can achieve this match expression.  Currently I am using,

```
([A-Za-z0-9-]+)
```

...which matches letters and numbers.  I would also like to match on dashes and underscores in the same expression.  Anyone know how?

I would like to be able to match **product_name** and **product-name**

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Just escape the dashes to prevent them from being interpreted (I don't think underscore needs escaping, but it can't hurt). You don't say which regex you are using.

```
([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+)
```

Comment: As a follow up, how can I apply the above rules while excluding periods?  I would like to ignore, for instance, image.png

Comment: @George Please don't ask follow-up questions anywhere except for new questions. Comments are not for that; answers are not for that; if you have a new question, ask a new question.

Comment: "but it can't hurt" --- yes it can if you're using it in HTML5, which will throw a "`Invalid regular expression: /([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+)/: Invalid escape`" error!. Use `([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+)` instead! :)

Comment: @John This will allow the string to start with a dash or underscore. Is there a way to disallow them at the start and end?

Answer (score 22):

Your expression should already match dashes, because the final - will not be interpreted as a range operator (since the range has no end). To add underscores as well, try:

```
([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)
```

Answer (score 20):

Depending on your regex variant, you might be able to do simply this:

```
([\w-]+)
```

Also, you probably don't need the parentheses unless this is part of a larger expression.

Comment: This is for a .htaccess file, so I need the parentheses since as you said, it is in a larger expression :)

Comment: This worked for me, and I think it's a little cleaner using the 'word' shortcut. Actually I used [\w-]*

Answer (score 2):

You can indeed match all those characters, but it's safer to escape the `-` so that it is clear that it be taken literally.

If you are using a [POSIX variant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes) you can opt to use:

`([[:alnum:]\-_]+)`

But a since you are including the underscore I would simply use:

`([\w\-]+)`

(works in all variants)