# How to validate pattern in input string?

Tags: php, validation

If I had a webpage and I neeed to ensure user input for a variable is only letters (upper and lower), numbers and dashes and the length had to be exactly 20 chars in length, how would one perform that?

Comment: You can figure out the regex part in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338044/regex-letters-numbers-dashes-and-underscores). The string length part should be pretty [simple](http://php.net/strlen).

Comment: Looks like assignment specification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is pretty easy to do using regular expressions:

```
echo preg_match('/^[0-9a-zA-Z\-]{20}$/', 'abcd');
0
echo preg_match('/^[0-9a-zA-Z\-]{20}$/', 'abcdefghijkmlnopqrst');
1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use regular expressions. See [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

Your regular expression could look something like:

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9\-]{20}$/
```

or

```
/^[\w-]{20}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't trust in regexp because of performance you may use the following, which will take longer:

```
function checkalphanum($str){
    $allowed = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_-ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    if(strlen($str) == 20){ return false;}
    for($i=0; $i < count($str); $i++){
        if(strpos($allowed, substr($str, $i, 1)) == -1){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```