# How to repair my C# regex that attempts to match 1-100 characters of letters, numbers, spaces, underscores and dashes

Tags: c#, .net, regex

So I have a field

```
    [RegularExpression(@"([A-Za-z0-9\-\_ ]+){1,100}"]
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

where the regex is attempting to match strings that are 1-100 characters long and contains only letters, numbers, underscores, dashes and spaces.

I am getting the exception

> Additional information: parsing "([A-Za-z0-9-_ ]+){1,100}" -
>   Unrecognized escape sequence _.

How can i fix this?

Comment: @Forklift I got that straight from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338044/regex-letters-numbers-dashes-and-underscores

Comment: You do not need the `(` and `)` and the escapes at all. Use `[RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z0-9-_ ]{1,100}"]`

Comment: Note that a hyphen inside `[]` might denote a range, but after a range it cannot define another range, so, you may just remove all escape symbols without moving the hyphen. However, it is best practice to put the hyphen at the start/end of the character class.

Comment: Typical MS junk. It makes you keep track of what the escape's _IT_ recognizes. Instead of letting them pass through by removing the escape. Utter chaos. Inside the class it recognizes `\-` as valid because it can be a range operator, or if escaped a literal.

Comment: Why did you accept a `([A-Za-z0-9\-_ ]+){1,100}` solution? It matches an infinite amount of letters, digits, hyphens and underscores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (get rid of the backslash before the underscore):

```
[RegularExpression(@"([A-Za-z0-9\-_ ]+){1,100}"]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove all escapes and the `+` and it is advisable to put the hyphen at the end of the character class to remove any ambiguity:

```
[RegularExpression("[A-Za-z0-9_ -]{1,100}"]
```

Since `RegularExpressionAttribute` pattern is always implicitly anchored, there is no need adding `^` in front and `$` at the end. `[A-Za-z0-9_ -]{1,100}` will match a string that consists of 1 to 100 chars that are either ASCII letters, digits, `_` space or `-`.

Comment: Another idea is to use `\w`, but it may match more than ASCII letters/digits  if run on server side. `[RegularExpression(@"[\w -]{1,100}"]`